# Can there be a p-Sylow subgroup of a p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Have two particular questions about the definition of p-Sylow subgroups:

1. In all the definitions I've seen, p-Sylow subgroups of a group $G$ are defined as maximal subgroups of $G$ such that their order is a power of p. After a definition makes that point, something like "i.e. a p-subgroup that is not contained in any other p-subgroup". So does "maximal" mean that a given p-Sylow subgroup is not contained in *any* proper subgroup of $G$, or that that a given p-Sylow subgroup may or may not be contained in *a* subgroup of $G$ if that subgroup is not a p-group (so maximal only with respect to the $p-$ part.
2. **The main question**: Suppose $G$ is a p-group. Then if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, by one of the definitions above (the latter one), it cannot be a p-Sylow subgroup of $G$ since then it would be contained in a (in this case, not proper, but nowhere is the exclusion made, as far as I know) p-subgroup of $G$ ($G$ itself).

This info has direct impact on a problem I'm working on. So at some point in that problem, we essentially consider a group $G$ and two subgroups $H$ and $K$ with $K$ defined as a p-Sylow subgroup. We eventually prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $H$ and that $H$ is a p-group. If the first definition in my first point is true and $K$ is maximal in the sense that it isn't contained in *any* proper subgroup of $G$, we need to consider both the case $H$ = $K$ and $H$ = $G$. But if we define it by the later definition and that definition doesn't restrict the 'maximality' of $K$ to *proper* subgroups of $G$, we need only consider the case $H = K$, because if $G = H$ but $H \neq K$ then that case immediately fails because $H$ not being a *proper* subgroup of $G$ would not free it from the requirement not to be a p-group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maximal means that a $p$-Sylow is not (properly) contained in any other $p$-subgroup of $G$; in other words, it means maximal in the poset of $p$-subgroups. Other subgroups are irrelevant.
2. Every $p$-group is its own $p$-Sylow. The keyword "other" is important here; it actually implies proper containment if you squint at it, although this is a bit confusing and it would be better to say "properly contained" to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition I learned for a Sylow p-subgroup is that if $G$ is a group of order $p^\alpha m$ where $p$ does not divide $m$, then a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^\alpha$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$. The notion of a Sylow p-subgroup $P$ is not meant to convey that $P$ is a maximal p-subgroup of $G$, but rather that $P$ is a p-subgroup of $\textbf{maximal order}$ in $G$. This does not exclude the possibility of a p-group having a Sylow p-subgroup.

Comment: Under the definition you give, it is immediate that every Sylow $p$-subgroup is necessarily a maximal $p$-subgroup. It is the other implication that is not immediate.

Comment: Maximal subgroups must be proper because otherwise a $G$ would be the only maximal subgroup of itself and the definition would not be very useful. We can take the approach where we include $G$ as a possibility for a "maximal p-subgroup", but that's taking extra steps for not much gain. However, I never argued that in the case where $G$ is not a p-group then a Sylow p-subgroup is not maximal. My point was to convey that it is more important to focus on the fact that defining it as a p-subgroup of maximal order is more useful and works in all circumstances.

Comment: "maximal $p$-subgroup" does not mean, as you seem to imply, "maximal subgroup that is a $p$-group", nor "$p$-subgroup that is a maximal subgroup". It means "subgroup which is maximal among all $p$-subgroups".  Your misunderstanding comes from the fact that while "maximal $X$ subgroup" always means "subgroup which is maximal among all subgroups with property $X$", we unfortunately break the rule for historical reasons when no $X$ is there and do not say "maximal proper subgroup", omitting "proper", leading sometimes to confusion. Your point is misguided, based on not realizing this.

Comment: In other words, the exception is made for "maximal subgroup", not for anything else. Both definitions are equally useful and logically equivalent for finite groups once you realize what the terms mean, so you are incorrect about one being "more useful" than the other. If anything, your definition is *less* useful because it cannot be used for infinite groups, while the one with "maximal $p$-subgroup" can.

Comment: (Let me take "only for maximal subgroup" back a bit... "maximal normal subgroup" usually means "maximal proper normal subgroup"... But the exceptions are few and far between to the general pattern.)

Comment: I apologize. I was not aware that Sylow subgroups applied to infinite groups as well. I've only learned abstract algebra from Dummit and Foote and those were the only definitions of Sylow subgroups and maximal subgroups I was given.